# EF Core populate nested navigation property with Collection.LoadAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In EF Core, I'm populating a navigation property ; `User.BookMarks` with `Collection.LoadAsync`:

```
public async override Task<User> Fetch(string id)
{
    var user = await entities.FindAsync(id);
    await context.Entry(user).Collection(i => i.BookMarks).LoadAsync();
    return user;
}
```

However, `BookMark` also has a navigation property, `BookMark.VgnItmEst` which is not being populated. How do I populate that too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not obvious directly from the docs, but you can insert [Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.collectionentry-2.query?view=efcore-7.0) method (available for both collection and reference navigation properties) call which

> Returns the query that would be used by `Load()` to load entities referenced by this navigation property.

and apply as many `Include` / `ThenInclude` you want (similar to eager loading) before calling `Load{Async}`. e.g.

```cs
await context.Entry(user).Collection(i => i.BookMarks)
    .Query()
    .Include(e => e.VgnItmEst)
    .LoadAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I Include `BookMark.User` also? Adding `.Include(e => e.User)` after the first Include is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? It is the same syntax as for [Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#including-multiple-levels), and with same resulting behavior. There shouldn't be a difference in `Include` behavior (I believe, otherwise there must be a bug in EFC version you are using).

Comment: I just realised it is working with `BookMark.User` after all. Thank you!

Comment: Btw, if `BookMark.User` is the inverse of the `User.Bookmarks`, then it should be loaded automatically when you the load collection (no include needed for that property).

Comment: Yes, `BookMark.User` is the inverse property. It is actually there also with your answer. My restarting may not have been working when I was seeing it missing. Thanks